# transfer data from other table and set field name as value

Tags: mysql

i have a query problem

i have a table

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| coding | prov | kota | kecamatan | kode | reg | etd_reg | oke | etd_oke | yes | 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | a    | a_1   | a_1_1    |   A  | 20  | 1 -2    | 22  | 2 -3    | 25  |
| 2      | a    | a_1   | a_1_2    |   A  | 19  | 2 -3    | 21  | 3 -5    | 24  |
| 3      | a    | a_1   | a_1_3    |   A  | 21  | 3 -5    | 23  | 5 -7    | 26  |
| 4      | a    | a_2   | a_2_1    |   A  | 22  | 1 -2    | 24  | 2 -3    | 27  |
| 5      | a    | a_2   | a_2_2    |   A  | 20  | 2 -4    | 22  | 4 -6    | 25  |
| 6      | b    | b_1   | b_1_1    |   B  | 22  | 7 -9    | -   | -       | -   |
| 7      | b    | b_1   | b_1_2    |   B  | 15  | 4 -5    | 17  | 6 -7    | 20  |
| 8      | b    | b_2   | b_2_1    |   B  | 27  | 2 -4    | -   | -       | -   |
| 9      | b    | b_2   | b_2_2    |   B  | 11  | 2 -3    | 13  | 3 -5    | 16  |
| 10     | b    | b_2   | b_2_3    |   B  | 23  | 1 -2    | 25  | 2 -3    | -   |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i want to transfer the data of that table to a new table like below

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | coding | prov | kota | kecamatan | kode | paket | cost |  etd  | 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | 1      | a    | a_1  | a_1_1     | A    | reg   | 20   |  1 -2 | 
|  2 | 1      | a    | a_1  | a_1_1     | A    | oke   | 22   |  2 -3 | 
|  3 | 1      | a    | a_1  | a_1_1     | A    | yes   | 25   |  1    | 
|  4 | 2      | a    | a_1  | a_1_2     | A    | reg   | 19   |  2 -3 | 
|  5 | 2      | a    | a_1  | a_1_2     | A    | oke   | 21   |  3 -5 | 
|  6 | 2      | a    | a_1  | a_1_2     | A    | yes   | 24   |  1    | 
|  7 | 3      | a    | a_1  | a_1_3     | A    | reg   | 21   |  3 -5 | 
|  8 | 3      | a    | a_1  | a_1_3     | A    | oke   | 23   |  5 -7 | 
|  9 | 3      | a    | a_1  | a_1_3     | A    | yes   | 26   |  1    | 
| 10 | 4      | a    | a_2  | a_2_1     | A    | reg   | 22   |  1 -2 | 
| 11 | 4      | a    | a_2  | a_2_1     | A    | oke   | 24   |  2 -3 | 
| 12 | 4      | a    | a_2  | a_2_1     | A    | yes   | 27   |  1    | 
| 10 | 5      | a    | a_2  | a_2_2     | A    | reg   | 20   |  2 -4 | 
| 11 | 5      | a    | a_2  | a_2_2     | A    | oke   | 22   |  4 -6 | 
| 12 | 5      | a    | a_2  | a_2_2     | A    | yes   | 25   |  1    | 
| 13 | 6      | b    | b_1  | b_1_1     | B    | reg   | 22   |  7 -9 | 
| 14 | 7      | b    | b_1  | b_1_2     | B    | reg   | 15   |  4 -5 | 
| 15 | 7      | b    | b_1  | b_1_2     | B    | oke   | 17   |  6 -7 | 
| 16 | 7      | b    | b_1  | b_1_2     | B    | yes   | 20   |  1    | 
| 17 | 8      | b    | b_2  | b_2_1     | B    | reg   | 27   |  2 -4 | 
| 14 | 9      | b    | b_2  | b_2_2     | B    | reg   | 11   |  2 -3 | 
| 15 | 9      | b    | b_2  | b_2_2     | B    | oke   | 13   |  3 -5 | 
| 16 | 9      | b    | b_2  | b_2_2     | B    | yes   | 16   |  1    | 
| 17 | 10     | b    | b_2  | b_2_3     | B    | reg   | 23   |  1 -2 | 
| 19 | 10     | b    | b_2  | b_2_3     | B    | oke   | 25   |  2 -3 | 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

actual data is more 5000 row.. is posible to transfer it??

if the value of field is - that not need to make new row

can someone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll have to create the new table. EG:

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, coding int, prov varchar(1), kota varchar(3),
  kecamatan varchar(5), kode varchar(1), paket varchar(3), cost int,
  etd varchar(4), PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Note that this table will contain the cost as an `int` (which is much better than a string, right?) so you'll have to convert it later (as you'll see in the query below).

Then you have to insert the data in this new table and union based on the different types of `kode`. EG:

```
INSERT INTO RESULT (coding, prov, kota, kecamatan, kode, paket, cost, etd)
SELECT coding, prov, kota, kecamatan, kode, 'reg' paket, reg+0 cost, etd_reg etd
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT coding, prov, kota, kecamatan, kode, 'oke' paket, oke+0 cost, etd_oke etd
FROM t
WHERE oke != '-'
UNION ALL
SELECT coding, prov, kota, kecamatan, kode, 'yes' paket, yes+0 cost, 1 etd
FROM t
WHERE yes != '-'
```

You can see this in action in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58669/1).